# Comparing Array values in JAVA (checking if words are anagrams)

Tags: java, arrays

How to check if the two arrays have same values, ignoring their position. The arrays can have multiple of same value.

Example 1

```
String[] a = {"m","o","m","d","a","d"};
String[] b = {"d","a","d","m","o","m"};
```

//This should result true.

Example 2

```
String[] a = {"m","o","m","d","a","d"};
String[] b = {"d","a","d","m","o"};
```

//This should result false because second array has only one m and first array has two

I hope my condition is understood by example.

I am trying to check if the words are anagrams. I have made array out of words. But could not check if the arrays have same values. My code is as follows:

```
public class AreAnagrams {
    public static boolean areAnagrams(String a, String b) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Waiting to be implemented.");
        if(a.length() != b.length()) return false;
        String[] test = new String[a.length()];
        String[] testb = new String[b.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++){
            test[i] = a.substring(i,i+1);
            testb[i] = b.substring(i,i+1);            
        }
        return test.equals(testb);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(areAnagrams("momdad", "dadmom"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your tried code...

Comment: We don't encourage questions that don't demonstrate minimal understanding, voting to close.

Comment: Sort both arrays before comparing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the two arrays with `Arrays.sort()` and then compare the sorted arrays with `Arrays.equals()` to find out if they have the same values.